# Length $x$ of part of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I can't calculate the length $x$ in this diagram.
What is $x$?

[image: Triangle]

I think some people misunderstood the question. Please see below picture.
[image]

To be frank, I tried to use two Pitagoras' formula as below (like others).
$$x^2 + y^2 = 3$$
$$x^2 + (y+\sqrt 3)^2 = 2^2$$
substituting $y^2 = 3 - x^2$, (or $y = \sqrt(3-x^2)$,
$$x^2+y^2+2\sqrt3y+3 = 4$$
$$x^2+3-x^2+2\sqrt3\sqrt{3-x^2}=1$$
$$2+2\sqrt3\sqrt{3-x^2}=0$$
$$1+\sqrt{9-3x^2}=0$$
This is unsolvable? What's wrong?

EDIT : I realized too late that the triangle is acute. when three sides are equal, they are 60 degrees. Even if two sides are $\sqrt3$, they are still acute(by comparison of $c^2$ and $a^2+b^2$ as A. Pongrácz told me. How stupid I was..

Comment: Did you try to use the Pythagorean theorem for both triangles with the right angle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just two pythagorean theorem:
[image]

Comment: please see my edited question. angle A is bigger than 90 degree.

Comment: @ChanKim, why are you insisting that angle A is obtuse?  By the law of cosines, angle A = acos(1/3), about 70.5 degrees.  Greater than an equilateral's 60 degrees, but nevertheless acute.

Comment: @Tebbe sorry, I misunderstood the situation.

Answer (score 1):

You will get two equations

$$\sqrt{3}^2=y^2+x^2$$
$$(\sqrt{3}-y)^2+x^2=4$$
Can you solve this?
The second equation is

$$3+x^2+y^2-2\sqrt{3}y=4$$

Comment: I tried it but turned out weird(no s real solution), I don't know what's wrong. I think using Heron's formula is a sure method.

Comment: I got real solutions for this system.

Comment: It should be $(\sqrt{3}-y)^2+x^2=4$

Answer (score 0):

It is the altitude. 
There are a couple of ways to compute it. 
An elegant one: compute the are of the triangle using Heron's formula, and then use the well-known formula that involves the area, a side and an altitude.

By the way, the picture is not really correct. The triangle should be acute, so the altitude intersects the opposite side between the vertices.

Comment: root (3) is less than then 2. (shorter than 2). Why should it be acute?

Comment: An equilateral triangle is actue. Gradually make the top two sides shorter, and it won't be obtuse until after it's right.

Comment: It is not equilateral.

Comment: @A.Pongrácz we can use bottom x height x 1/2 to calculate the area anyway.

Comment: Before I answer, I assume I am the "some people" who misunderstood the question. Well, I don't think so. The triangle is acute, so the picture is still incorrect. The expression that decides if the angle $\gamma$ is smaller or bigger than $90^\circ$ is the sign of $a^2+b^2-c^2$, which in this case is $3+3-4>0$. So $\gamma<90^\circ$. Check the cosine law. The fact that $\sqrt{3}<2$ has nothing to do with it.

Comment: You are wrong. Stop repeating the same wrong argument, and instead, start thinking about my comment. Did you check the cosine law? That will clearly show you that the apex angle is about $70.53^\circ$.

Comment: Oh, sorry now I get it.

Comment: I would appreciate if we could conclude this argument now.

Comment: So you don't like my answer any more? That is nice. You are welcome, by the way.